# start xscreensaver from cron@reboot, Ubuntu startup, or service/daemon?

Tags: cron, services, xscreensaver

I need start xscreensaver for Ubuntu, and it can be started in Ubuntu startup application.

My questions are:

- can xscreensaver be started in cron@reboot?
- can xscreensaver be started in service/deamon?
- can we start GUI program from a Linux service or daemon?